# Download txt file anonymously from Google drive using C#.Net

Tags: c#, .net, download, google-drive-api

I'm making a simple program with C#.Net that provides some clients with links which are continuously updated ,and I need to provide a simple text database for my app.

I need to use Google drive to make it easy to edit the database by some users.

So ,how can I download a text or doc file uploaded to Google drive and shared publicly ?

Comment: You could write a program to download the text file.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following Google Drive SDK

https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/dotnet